# wp_dequeue_script for a Plugin

Tags: plugins, php, functions, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to remove a line of script in the footer of my page that a plugin is inserting on pages that I am not using the plugin at, homepage for example. I am using the below code for some reason it will still display the script. Any suggestions?

The line I need removed: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://domain.com/wp-content/plugins/jet-reviews/assets/js/lib/vue.min.js?ver=2.6.11' id='jet-vue-js'></script>`

The code in my functions.php

```
function review_enqueue() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
       wp_dequeue_script('jet-vue-js');
    }
}
add_action('wp_dequeue_scripts', 'review_enqueue');
```

Comment: There is no `wp_dequeue_scripts` action, have you contacted jet reviews support? 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here

Comment: You're applying this incorrectly:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/  You will then also need to make sure this executes after the plugin has already registered the script.

Answer (score 1):

It still displays the script because you are using the wrong hook (and it doesn't exist) — `wp_dequeue_scripts`, and secondly, if the script is indeed enqueued via [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), then the generated `id` (used in the `<script>` tag) is in the form of `<script handle>-js` (i.e. suffixed with a `-js`) where `<script handle>` is the first parameter for `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Therefore in your case, the script handle is just `jet-vue` without the `-js`, and try dequeuing the script via the `wp_print_scripts` hook instead.

```php
function review_enqueue() {
        if ( is_front_page() ) {
             wp_dequeue_script( 'jet-vue' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'review_enqueue' );
```

If that doesn't work, you can try using a lower priority (i.e. a greater number) as the 3rd parameter for `add_action()`. E.g.

```php
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'review_enqueue', 20 );
```

And if that still doesn't work, then try contacting the plugin support and ask them for the proper way to dequeue their scripts. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While I think your code is accurate, it still didn't work. Might be something the plugin is doing to prevent it from being changed. I will reach out to the plugin developer as mentioned. Thanks

Comment: If you're sure the `<script>` tag is still there, you can also try `is_home()` or `is_home() || is_front_page()` with the `if`, before reaching out to the plugin support.